# strace on Ubuntu Core

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core, strace

How do I get strace running on Ubuntu Core?

I installed the `strace-static` snap (there is no `strace` snap), but it fails when attempting to run it:

```
# strace-static ls
/snap/strace-static/18/bin/strace: ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, ...): Operation not permitted
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

I attempted to switch the snap to devmode, following the description on the `snap help refresh`:

```
refresh command options]
          --devmode            Put snap in development mode and disable security confinement
```

This fails

```
# snap refresh strace-static --devmode
snap "strace-static" has no updates available
```

And still have the same issue afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Removing and readding the snap with devmode works:

```
snap remove strace-static

snap install strace-static --devmode
```

The error (Basically see `snap help refresh`) when trying to change it to devmode with install without removing it and a quick scan of the help for `snap refresh` gives the impression that it can be fixed with `snap refresh`

Comment: Thanks for that answer- really helpful Gert!  Certainly couldn't get the answer from `man` pages: snaps has no support from them...